# Redirect Drupal 6 to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, drupal-6

My Drupal 6 installation was installed via a server installation profile. I need to change the base URL from example.com to dev.example.com.

I've already changed this in settings.php and baseurl.php. There is no individial .htaccess file for this site. What do I do here? Should I create a new .htaccess file or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You have to create new .htaccess file and include this code at the bottom

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !oldexample.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newexample.com/$1 [L,R=301]

hope it will help you!!.

Comment: I got the server guy to do it, and I assume this is what he did. Thanks!!